# Printing views exposed sort criteria separately to exposed filters

Tags: 7, views

Exposed filters are either:
- Printed in views-view.tpl.php using the $exposed variable.
- Printed in a block, probably using the same variable.

This variable ($exposed) contains the exposed sort criteria and filters. I would like to find a way to print them separately. Ideally there would be  a way to use something like:

```
<div id="sort"><?php print $exposed->sort; ?></div>
<div id="filter"><?php print $exposed->filter; ?></div>
```

Does anyone know of a way you can achieve this? Or in last case how to print each sort and criteria individually?

Comment: I found how to individually print filters in views-exposed-form.tpl.php: http://drupal.org/node/674910#comment-2444650

Comment: hello @ipwa, each widget still must be inside exposed form, or I am wrong?

Comment: What I need is to have filters in a collapsible fieldset and sort criteria under the fieldset (using toggle links with better exposed filters module). So yes, they can still be in the same form, just separated by markup.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not use each item of $widgets in separated way, you can `push` each widget in a separated array for use each widget across your custom html.

```
<?php foreach($widgets as $id => $widget): ?>
    <?php
    array_push($elements, $widget);
    ?>  
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php
echo $elements[0]->widget;
echo $elements[1]->widget;
//etc
?>
```